# Publishing locally with Gradle not working

Tags: java, gradle, publishing

I have the following directory structure:

```
myapp/
    src/main/resources/
        <lots of code>
    build.gradle
```

With the following `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
targetCompatibility = '1.8'

[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

group = 'net.myuser'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile(
        <dependencies here>
    )
}

jar {
    baseName = 'myapp'
}

task writePom << {
    pom {
        project {
            groupId group
            artifactId 'myapp'
            version version

            inceptionYear '2015'
            licenses {
                license {
                    name 'myapp'
                    distribution 'Blah blah blah'
                }
            }
        }
    }.writeTo("build/libs/pom.xml")
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
    archives javadocJar
}

artifacts {
    archives(file("${buildDir}/libs/myapp-${version}.jar")) {
        name "myapp"
        classifier ""
    }
}
```

When I do:

```
./gradlew clean build writePom install -Pversion=0.1.0
```

I get two problems:

1. Inside the generated `build/libs/pom.xml` the `groupId` is showing as `null`; and
2. I cannot find a `net.myuser` directory under `~/.gradle/caches/modules-2`, which tells me `install` is not working

So I ask: **What do I need to change so that `groupId` isn't null, and how do I get `install` publishing all of the following:**

- JAR
- Sources JAR
- Javadoc JAR
- `pom.xml`

Comment: Have you tried `groupId project.group` instead of `groupId group`?

Comment: Thanks @thokuest (+1) - that solves my first problem (where `pom.xml` now has correct `groupId` value), but the artifacts are still not publishing under that `modules-2` directory. Any ideas?!? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comment, use `groupId project.group` instead of `groupId group` in order to set the `<groupId>` properly.

---

Regarding the `install` task, please have a look at [Gradle Maven Plugin documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html):

> Installs the associated artifacts to the local Maven cache, including Maven metadata generation.

By default, the *local Maven cache* is located in `~/.m2/repository`, thus you are looking at the wrong location. The install task does not tamper with `~/.gradle/caches/modules-2` which is (as the name already implies) only a cache for resolved dependencies.

---

By using the Maven plugin, Gradle already creates a POM file for you. So please check if you really need a custom `writePom` task.

Also, the main artifact is installed automatically, so this might be redundant:

```
artifacts {
    archives(file("${buildDir}/libs/myapp-${version}.jar")) {
        name "myapp"
        classifier ""
    }
}
```